# Dependency Injection with Cyclic Dependency

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Let me have two very basic objects like:

```
public class View
{
    public View(Controller controller)
    {
        // Use the model exposed by the controller here
    }
}

public class Controller
{
    private readonly IView view;

    public Controller()
    {
        this.view = new View(this);
    }

    public Controller(View v)
    {
        this.view = v;
    }
}
```

Later I decide to inject View object into the Controller via DI but there I have a cyclic dependency (i.e. I can't use `var ctrl = new Controller(new View(ctrl));`). How would you go about injectin the dependency in this case?

Comment: Are you going to have multiple views for one controller?

Comment: Nope just one. I'm trying to avoid property injection in this case though.

Comment: So why adding the DI resolution for view? There will be 1:1 relationship between view and controller. Sorry, I don't see the point of it.

Comment: Sorry now I got what you meant (I thought you were asking about single instance). Yes there will multiple views (gui, cli, etc.)

Comment: Then I suggest to have ctor like `Controller(IView view)`, remove the `controller` parameter from `View` and add a property for setting `Controller` instance in `View`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common solution is to use a dependency property to solve circular dependencies. i.e. create a new property in one of the classes and let the IoC container assign it.

If you are using Unity you should add `[Dependency]` to that property.

A sidenote: A View should not have a dependency to a controller. It should not be aware of it at all.

**Update in reply to comment**

You can't. That's the problem with circular dependencies. The only other solution is to use composition. That is to break out the common functionality into a separate class and include it in both the controller and the view.

Comment: Yes actually the view only uses the model (for databinding) exposed by the controller, tried to be concise in this case. By the way, I'm trying to avoid property injection (as dependencies are crucial to the class functionality).

Comment: yep, you're right on that, seems like I'll have to go with prop-inj. or another exotic solution.

Comment: Your own answer is a variant of the Service Locator Pattern. You could also create a `ViewFactory` which takes the controller as a parameter and take it as a constructor parameter in the controller.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent `ViewFactory` idea, should have thought of that before.. moving forward with the factory implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a nice solution using Ninject.

```
public class Controller
{
    private readonly View view;

    public Controller(ViewModule viewModule)
    {
        using (IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(viewModule))
        {
            this.view = kernel.Get<View>(new ConstructorArgument("controller", this);
        }
    }
}
```

Where the ViewModule is a pre-configured Ninject module to resolve the particular view dependency (GUI, CLI, etc.) Minor problem here is that, I'm now dependent on the particular DI framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that at all with constructor-injection
If you change the constructor of the controller to

```
public Controller(IView view)
```

in which order would you create the two objects?
View needs the controller Instance and the controller needs the view.
However, you can make the IView Property of the controller public, and set the Property after creation (Some DI-Containers can do this for you automatically when you set the correct attribute).